# Strange behaviour of bar chart when using twinx in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have been battling this for too long, to the point that I'm pretty sure I don't understand the implementation of `twinx` in matplotlib

ok I have some code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data1 = [5, 6, 6, 7]
err1 = [1, 1, 1, 1]
data2 = [0.5, 0.6]
err2 = [0.01, 0.01]

label1 = ['var1', 'var2', 'var3', 'var4']
label2 = ['var5', 'var6']
```

If I just want to plot data 1 everything is fine.

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.bar(label1, data1, yerr=err1, color='red')
plt.show()
```

This gives me a pretty chart 
[image]

If I want to add data 2 onto a second axis I lose columns and the order is also odd.

```
ax1.bar(label1, data1, yerr=err1, color='red')
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.bar(label2, data2, yerr=err2, color='blue')
plt.show()
```

Does not give me six columns but only 4 with two of the data1 columns now missing?

[image]

Obviously Im 100% sure its my fault, but please someone put me out of this misery...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your bars are overlapping and therefore you see two less bars. The solution is to use well-defined x-values for positioning your bars and then after you have plotted on twin axis, assign the x-tick labels.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data1 = [5, 6, 6, 7]
err1 = [1, 1, 1, 1]
data2 = [0.5, 0.6]
err2 = [0.01, 0.01]

label1 = ['var1', 'var2', 'var3', 'var4']
label2 = ['var5', 'var6']

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.bar(range(len(label1)), data1, yerr=err1, color='red')

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.bar(range(4,6), data2, yerr=err2, color='blue')
ax2.set_xticks(range(6))
ax2.set_xticklabels(label1+label2)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent - In the docs, I interpreted the `the x coordinates of the bars' as referring to the labels - which works with a single plot but clearly not with two axes.

Comment: @nick.sculthorpe: You don't need to pass `range(4)` etc. while plotting on single axis. There you can do as you did already. But for twin axis, you want to plot the blue bars successively at x=4 and 5. Therefore you need to use 0, 1, 2, 3 for the left y-axis

Answer (score 1):

You can also do:

```py
label = ['var1', 'var2', 'var3', 'var4', 'var5', 'var6']
data1 = [5, 6, 6, 7, np.NaN, np.NaN]
data2 = [np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, 0.5, 0.6]
```

The issue here is that a matplotlib axes converts to integers: 'var1'->1, 'var2'->2 etc, and `ax2` is a new axes so 'var4'->1, 'var5'->2 and you get the overlap.  Making your categories the same between the twinned axes clears this confusion up.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - @Bazingaa explained how to fix it, but I stil found it odd that Matplotlib would add a right hand axis but then add the columns to the left hand side.  At least the underlying mechanics now make some kind of sense.

Comment: Those two axes don't really know much about each other, except the x-limits they share.  Its possible that an improvement would be that they share "converters" (i.e. the thing that translates from "category" to integers), but that is a bit of complexity that hasn't been tried yet.